# Cumulative SUMIFS function which resets when a condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate a running total (in column G) of all files where the status is within an allowed list (AD, AM or AO), but also have the count reset for each new operator. Please note that the statuses and operators have been censored and so are not actually this consistent in length. Column H is a manual calculation of what should appear in G (ignore the cell colours, I have just added those in to visually differentiate the counts).

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Excel Screenshot:

[image]

I have tried a multitude of different `SUMIFS()` formula variations, which accurately count up the number of files in allowed statuses, but I cannot work out how to have the sum reset after each operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit complex formula. Try-

```
=LET(
tmp,SCAN("",B2:B20,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(OR(x="",x="total"),a,x))),
MAP(D2:D20,C2:C20,tmp,
LAMBDA(d,c,b,
SUM(FILTER(D2:d,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C2:c,{"AD","AM","AO"}))*(TAKE(tmp,ROW(d)-ROW(D1))=b))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution could be:

```
=LET(b,B2:B33, c,C2:C33, d,D2:D33,
     MAP(b,c,d,
  LAMBDA(x,y,z,
     LET(u,TAKE(b,1), v,TAKE(c,1), w,TAKE(d,1),
         a,LAMBDA(e,f, XLOOKUP(1,(u:x<>"")*(u:x<>"Total"),e:f,,,-1):f),
SUM((a(v,y)={"AD","AO","AM"})*a(w,z))))))
```

First we declare the ranges `b`, `c` and `d` and MAP them as `x`, `y` and `z`.
We than declare the start of these ranges `u`, `v` and `w` (we could also use `B2`, `C2` and `D2`).
We than create a lambda function called `a` which looks up from B2:current row of column B  (from end to start) to not be blank or to not equal "Total" and returns the cell that meats these conditions. Since XLOOKUP returns a cell, we can use that in range reference and reference from that XLOOKUP result until the current row of that column; so `a(v,y)` means `XLOOKUP(1,(u:x<>"")*(u:x<>"Total"),C2:y,,,-1):y` or in words: *Column C with start row - the last found row number in column B  to not contain "Total" or blank values in rows prior to or equal to current row - up to current row*

If we check this range of column B to contain `{"AD","AO","AM"}` and sum the values of the same rows in column C, you get your required SUM.

different notation:
`=LET(a,B2:D33,MAP(INDEX(a,,1),INDEX(a,,2),INDEX(a,,3),LAMBDA(b,c,d,LET(x,LAMBDA(y,z,XLOOKUP(1,(B2:b<>"")*(B2:b<>"Total"),y:z,,,-1):z),SUM((x(C2,c)={"AD","AO","AM"})*x(D2,d))))))`